Why does Groves believe the Manhattan Engineer District is "problem number one" for Oppenheimer and many physicists?
In a lecture hall, Colonel Groves and Lt. Colonel Nichols meet Oppenheimer. Groves hands
his coat to Nichols for cleaning, prompting a comment from Oppenheimer about Nichols’
treatment. Groves playfully jabs at Oppenheimer’s physicist status. Groves then expresses
his regret about staying in Washington despite global conflicts, intriguing Oppenheimer:

Groves: I built the Pentagon. The brass likes it so much they made me
take over the Manhattan Engineer District.
Oppenheimer: Which is?
Groves: Don't be a smart ass. You know damn well what it is. You and
half of every physics department across the country. That's problem
number one.

Why does Groves believe the Manhattan Engineer District is "problem number one" for Oppenheimer and many physicists?

He doesn't believe the Manhattan Engineer District is problem number one for Oppenheimer and half of every physics department across the country. He believes that Oppenheimer and half of every physics department across the country knowing damn well what the Manhattan Engineer District is is problem number one for himself.

Groves is in charge of, amongst other things, information security. His fundamental problem is that scientists are notoriously chatty and talk amongst themselves, even when they shouldn't. This means that the 'top secret' Manhattan Project, is actually anything but. Groves illustrates this by pointing out that every scientist of any note that he approaches (such as Oppenheimer) already knows key details about the project, regardless of their clearance level.
By extension, given how extensively America's enemies have infiltrated academic circles, every discovery made by the Manhattan team is being funnelled directly to the bad guys.
Groves' "Problem number one" is how does he get all these scientists to effectively collaborate to build a hyper-advanced bomb, but in a way that allows him to maintain information secrecy from America's enemies, who are also trying to do the same

And not just America's enemies, also their friends.  England was not pleased with how much information the US withheld from them.

@SottoVoce "We have no eternal allies, and we have no perpetual enemies. Our interests are eternal and perpetual." - Palmerston.
